# Assembly - TEST dx,dx followed by jg

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to x86 assembler and having a hard time interpreting all the conditional jumps and tests correctly. I have this code:

```
 sbb     dx, dx
 test    dx, dx
 jg      short loc_17C7
```

This is how I read that code: Before the `sbb`, `CF` is either set or not, so the result of `sbb dx, dx` is that you have either -1 or 0 in `dx`.

But then `test dx, dx` can never lead to any combination of FLAGS that would make `jg` jump. Wikipedia says

> The TEST operation sets the flags CF and OF to zero. The SF is set to the MSB of the result of the AND. If the result of the AND is 0, the ZF is set to 1, otherwise set to 0.

If `dx` is -1, that would lead to `OF=0 SF=1 ZF=0` (-1 should be all 1s in binary, so the MSB must be 1, thus SF=1)

If `dx` is 0, that would lead to `OF=0 SF=0 ZF=1`

But `jg` only jumps iff `ZF=0 and SF=OF`. In case 1, `SF!=OF`. In case 2, `ZF!=0`.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: I believe your conclusions are correct. `JGE` would make sense; `JZ` would make sense. `JC` rather than all three instructions would likely make even more sense (or the inverse of these instructions - futile to speculate on code that doesn't work anyway) - No apparent way of reaching the instruction following the `jg` - unless it's labelled - `loc_17c7` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing anything.

This code was probably generated by a non-optimizing (at least in this case) compiler.

The sbb doesn't even matter here:

```
 test    dx, dx
 jg      short loc_17C7
```

Obviously, a value can never be greater than itself.

Comment: The sbb DOES matter -- if it's not present, the value in `dx` might be something other than 0 or -1; the branch will be taken if its a positive non-zero value.

Comment: @ChrisDodd (& Simon): My bad - I got `test` mixed up with `cmp`. The latter sets flag the same as `sub` would but preserves the value. `test` OTOH does the same as `and` would but preserves the value.